# Behaviour when declaring non-optional parameter after optional parameter

Tags: php, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Let's define this function:

```
function fooFunction($a, $b='foo', $c){}
```

If I call it like:

```
$foo = fooFunction("bar", "buzz");
```

...will 'buzz' be asigned to $c or to $b?

Comment: lol - which IDE you are using?

Comment: I always thought it was assigned to $b, but my IDE (PHPStorm) disagrees.

Comment: You should raise the bug to PHP Storm :p

Comment: I would have thought it was bad design to have default values on anything but the last parameters anyway.

Comment: weird. How is that possible even oO

Comment: @NigelRen In my opinion it is **terrible** design. I just found it in my code base and I got curious about it when my IDE was complaining that the "buzz" was being assigned to $c and there was a type mismatch.

Comment: @ajreal I will if and when I recieve a solid answer, so I'm sure it really is a bug and PHP doesn't behave like that. It's PHP, so... who knows?

Comment: You could just try it… https://3v4l.org/rWN4g: `Missing argument 3 for fooFunction()`

Comment: @deceze That's what I thought it would happen, but I could swear that it was being called with just 2 parameters and not failing. Could I get an official reference for that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The presence or absence of default values for a parameter does not in any way influence what arguments will be assigned to what parameters; the first passed argument always goes to the first parameter, the second to the second and so on. If no value was passed for a parameter and it has a default value, its default value is used instead.

In PHP <7.1, not supplying an argument for parameters without default value merely produced a warning. The parameter would then be undefined inside the function:

```
function fooFunction($a, $b='foo', $c) {
    var_dump($c);
}

$foo = fooFunction("bar", "buzz");
```

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for fooFunction()

Notice: Undefined variable: c
NULL
```

Since PHP 7.1 it finally acts sane and throws an exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError:
  Too few arguments to function fooFunction(),
  2 passed and exactly 3 expected
Stack trace:
#0 fooFunction('bar', 'buzz')
```

It's still insane that you can define parameters without default value *after* parameters with, since in practice that makes little sense; perhaps PHP is counting on you not to do that precisely because there's no practical purpose.